# Associated each modal to an id

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I want each of my modal to have a unique ID.  But what I am actually doing is giving me:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #myModal(7)

Below is my code:

```
<tbody class="tbodyBookTable">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr class="trBookTable">
            <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateRented)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReturnDate)</th>
            <th>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookID))">Yes</button>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="#myModal(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookID))" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                      <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Return confirmation</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Are you sure you want to return this book?.</p>
                            <p>Book title:@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

As you can see, I am setting my `data-target` as

> #myModal(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookID))

and the id of my model in the same way.  I don't understand why I am getting this error.  Any help please?

Comment: Use brackets `[]` instead of paranthesis `()` when writing your attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the hashtag symbol (#) from the `id` declaration:

```
<div id='myModal(' + @Html.DisplayFor(item =>  item.BookID) + ')'></div>
```

The `data-target` uses the hashtag symbol because it is then placed directly into jQuery to find the element. When writing the `id` of an HTML element, you do not write the `#` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't building the `id` correct. Use these:

```
<div id='myModal(' + @Html.DisplayFor(item =>  item.BookID) + ')'></div>
```

Since `#` can be conflictive, don't use in elements id.